# Data.Table aggregation in R?

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

I have the following simple data.table:

```
   A B
1: 1 1
2: 1 1
3: 1 2
4: 1 2
```

Now what I want to have is simply:

```
   A B
1: 1 1
2: 1 2
```

I want to do this in data.table since it is very fast, so I try:

```
dt[,,by=list(A, B)]
```

and it does suprisingly nothing. How do I group the data.table fast together?

PS: I'm now doing this:

```
dt[,sum(A),by=list(A, B)]
```

and simply drop the last column (very inefficient imho).

Thanks!

Comment: You want to remove duplicate in your example. Try `dt[!duplicated(dt),]`

Comment: Lol, I feel ashamed. I am asking the wrong question. Thanks! Please turn it into an answer so that I can give you points.

Comment: `unique(dt)` would be slightly more direct. Check out `?unique` and read about the additional `by` argument as well.